# Is there any way to export product data from fb shop / catalogue?

Tags: wordpress, facebook

The thing is i initially start selling from fb so i added lot of products in facebook but now i created a WordPress site and i want to export from facebook and import to wordpress site. is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The only helpful thing to export that are available now are to export the product performance.

You can do it in "Insight -> Catalogue", it includes product names, then you can work and fill out the rest with that.

Unfortunately we cannot get any of price, image, and other attributes without Facebook marketing api. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/products/#Reading

[image: Export button in performance page]

Answer (score 0):

a better way is to go to catalogue items and expand all products then selct them manualy and ctrl c and then go to google sheet and past like in the image below:

[image]